# HYPERV_VIRTUAL_SWITCH deprecated, to replace by what?

Tags: redhat-containers

following the tutorial for windows https://developers.redhat.com/products/cdk/hello-world/#fndtn-windows it is mentioned to use HYPERV_VIRTUAL_SWITCH

when launching "minishift start", it is mentioned that using this environment variable is deprecated.

-- Check if deprecated options are used ...
   Use of HYPERV_VIRTUAL_SWITCH has been deprecated
   Please use: minishift config set hyperv-virtual-switch ExternalVirtualSwitch
FAIL

Where to report to improve the "hello world"?

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case you would like to report an issue with "Hello world" at developers.redhat.com you should open a jira for [JBoss Developer](https://issues.jboss.org) issue tracking system under project "Docs for Red Hat Developers" that can be found under shortcut [RHDEVDOCS](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/RHDEVDOCS/summary) or if you would prefer to raise an issue under Container Development Kit itself report here [CDK](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/CDK/summary).

P.S. You probably need to be registered.